# Segmentation Fault GDALRasterBand::ReportError(CPLErr, int, char const*, ...) () from /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20

Tags: python, c++, numpy, gdal

I must have changed or updated my packages recently because I now have this error when launching a Python script (embedded in C++):

```
ERROR 1: NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.2 but current library version is 1.11
```

Here are the packages I call in the Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gdal as gd
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource, Normalize
import Image
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
import sys
```

When I type: gdalinfo --version
I get: GDAL 2.2.2, released 2017/09/15

I think I have other versions of Python and GDAL on my computer now, but I cannot find how to solve this error.

I can run the python code without problem using python2.7, it seems it is only when the code is called from my C++ code that I get this error.

I use this function to load the python code into the C++ program:

```
PithonExtension::PithonExtension(char* pithon_path, char* pithon_filename,
        char* program_name, const std::string& repository) {

    Py_SetProgramName(program_name);

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Log
    PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* io_stdout = PyFile_FromFile(stdout, "stdout", "a", nullptr);
    PyObject_SetAttrString(sys, "stdout", io_stdout);
    PyObject* io_stderr = PyFile_FromFile(stderr, "stderr", "a", nullptr);
    PyObject_SetAttrString(sys, "stderr", io_stderr);
    PyObject* io_stdin = PyFile_FromFile(stdin, "stdin", "r", nullptr);
    PyObject_SetAttrString(sys, "stdin", io_stdin);

    // Tell the program where to find the python file we will launch.
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(pithon_path);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);

    // First, import module.
    PyObject* myModuleString = PyString_FromString(pithon_filename);
    PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);

    // Then getting a reference to your function.
    PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"workflow");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyString_FromString(repository.c_str()));

    // Then getting your result.
    PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);
}
```

GDB tells me: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe0fcb390 in GDALRasterBand::ReportError(CPLErr, int, char const*, ...) () from /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20